# How to reinitialize a Singleton (KafkaProducer) during runtime?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, apache-kafka, singleton

I've a class which creates Kafka producers based on configs from a dynamic cahce. The configs were pretty much fixed, but now we are exploring the possibility of *re-initializing* the Kafka producer if the config has been changed at runtime.
The cahce is basically a HashMap which is refreshed periodically from a DB.

What I've done now is to check the Cache to before I send the message and if the value is changed call the init() method which has a double check lock.

```
private volatile String config;
init(){
...
}

sendMessage(String message, String topic){
  if(config != Cahce.config())
  synchronized(){
    if(config != Cahce.config())
    init();
  }
}
```

I've tested this out in Dev environment it seems to work and unit testing was a pain(lot of mocks). I'm also currently modifying it so that the init() part is moved to a Factory.

I wanted to check if the implementation can be done any better ?
Also I see a Sonar warning on this line:

```
private volatile String config;
```

This is what I've in mind so far, still not sure if I need an AbstractFactory:
[image: Kafka factory]
The application uses Spring.

Comment: The code you presented is pretty much the "proper" double-checked locking solution. There is no way to simplify the code unless you can live with the fact that you lock the whole object when `sendMessage(...)` is called. I wonder if a singleton is the right pattern for your use case...

Comment: yeah .. the double check lock is ok I guess, I was just thinking how else can I move the init() out of the way. The current code is almost impossible to test. It is already in singleton scope, the double-check-lock is just for the re-init() part.

Comment: That was what my last sentence was about: I am sceptical that a singleton is the right pattern for your problem. The underlying question is: why do you have to reconfigure the Kafka factory?